# graphviz : parallel edges in undirected graph overlap

Tags: graphviz

```
graph {

0--1;
0--2;
0--1;
}
```

In the above  the parallel edges between 0 and 1 is drawn as single edge when jpg is generated using dot command.  Is it possible to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Using GraphViz v.2.28.0, `dot -Tjpg -o12.jpg 12.dot` on Windows XP, where the your graph above is in `12.dot`, shows the parallel edges between 0 and 1 quite clearly and distinctly. Could you say exactly what version you're using and exactly what command you're using?

Comment: I am using GraphViz v.2.30.1 and command is  "dot -Tjpg test.dot -o test.jpg"

Comment: In that case, it could perhaps be a bug in GraphViz v2.30 that wasn't in v2.28. You say that the problem occurs when producing jpg files. Does it also occur with other output file types?

Comment: yes.. even png has same problem..

Comment: Thinking about it, I wonder if the code to produce a .png file would have a great deal in common with the code to produce a .jpg file, given that they are both bitmaps? Have you tried a vector format like ps, svg or vrml?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your version. I get the following output:

[image]

You can also try playing with the **splines** graph attribute: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:splines

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, this should do what you need.

```
graph {

0--1 [color="black:white:black"];
0--2;

}
```